# Complex structure on cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

If $M$ is a complex manifold with complex structure $J$, why does the cotangent bundle of $M$ carry a natural complex structure, and not an almost complex structure. Is that obvious?

Comment: Do you mean the cotangent bundle viewed as a vector bundle, is a complex vector bundle, or do you mean that the cotangent bundle viewed as a manifold is a complex manifold?

Comment: I mean viewed as a manifold.

Comment: I guess it is ovious, using holomorphic charts for $M$ you can presumably define holomorphic charts for $T^*M$, the usual charts will do I believe. What have you tried?

Comment: The same, but I had some question about that, I was little bit confused why that question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olivier suggests, you can define a complex structure on $T^*M$ directly using the complex structure on $M$. This is basically the complex version of Proposition $3.18$ of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition) except that instead of $T^*M$, Lee is using $TM$. If you would like further information on this approach, let me know.